# Вопрос по NavDrawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-navigation-drawer

Здравствуйте. Весь день пытаюсь внедрить NavigationDrawer в своё приложение. И ни как не могу понять несколько вещей:
1) Хочу сделать разделитель между пунктами.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item ... />
    <item ... />
    <item ... />

</group>
<group>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="Настройки">
    </item>
</group>
```

Кнопка "настройки" уезжает куда-то вниз и нет разделителя. Подскажите, как правильно сделать его.

2) NavDrawer не задвигается обратно свайпом. Кроме тулбара здесь ничего толком не понимаю. Что здесь не так?

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простого разделителя без заголовка требуется id для group, например так:

```
<group android:id="@+id/nav_divider">
   <item
        android:id="@+id/nav3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_picture_as_pdf_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text3" />
   <item
        android:id="@+id/nav4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_picture_as_pdf_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text4" />
</group>
```

Comment: Странно, у меня тот же самый результат, без разделителя

Answer (score 1):

Каждый `<item>` добавь в `<group>` и каждому `<group>` присвой `id`

Примерно так будет выглядеть:

```
<group>
<item
    android:id="@+id/allproduct"
    android:icon="@drawable/all_products"
    android:title="@string/all_products" />
</group>

<group>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/favorite_prods"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
    android:title="Избранные" />
</group>


<group>
<item
    android:id="@+id/addProduct"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_product_icon"
    android:title="@string/add_product" />
</group>

<group>
<item
    android:id="@+id/myAds"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_items"
    android:title="@string/myproducts" />
</group>
```